# Taylor expansion of exponential operator

Tags: operators

I have an operator:

$$ \hat O = e^{\hat A+\hat B}$$

Is it correct to write its first order Taylor expansion by:

$$\hat O = 1+\hat A+\hat B$$

Comment: how is $\mathrm e^{\hat Q}$ defined?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Their comutator is [A,B]=1

Comment: what is the *definition* of the exponential of an operator?

Comment: A and B are general operators!

Comment: He's asking because the answer to your question follows from definition of the exponential of an operator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential - First equation gives you your answer

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is. The definition of the exponential of an operator is

$$\exp(\hat X) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\hat X^k}{k!} = \hat1+\hat X+\frac{\hat X^2}{2}+\dots$$

where $\hat 1$ is the identity operator. So if you stop at the first order you will have indeed

$$\exp(\hat A+\hat B) = \hat 1 + (\hat A + \hat B) $$